# Executable can't find DLL but DependencyWalker Can

Tags: c++, windows, dll, environment-variables

I am building an installer for an SDK, and I install a bunch of DLLs that I put in a directory in `\Program Files`.  I then add that directory to the %PATH% environment variable.  I also install some sample source code in a directory on the Desktop.

When I compile the source code and try to run the Executable I get an error that the DLLs are missing from my computer.  But when I run DependencyWalker on the Executable, DependencyWalker can find the DLLs on the %PATH% exactly where they should be.

How can I tell the Executable where to find the DLL?

Comment: executable is 32bit and system 64bit ?

Comment: No, it should all be 64 bit...

Comment: It doesn't make any difference, but you use the DLLs by linking against the associated LIBs, or do you [LoadLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) them? Anyway seems that your _PATH_ env var changes (__assuming the new paths are correct__) are not propagated in the environment where you try running the executable from (whether is a _cmd_ console, or the IDE), most likely it was started before you altered _PATH_? Try looking at _PATH_ contents (on that particular environment).